# Regular expressions with question mark

Tags: regex

`colou?r` matches `color` and `colour`

but what does the following `?` do?

```
(first group)(second group)?(third group)
```

Comment: This will be your best friend when using regexp: http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/

Comment: Should be well explained here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html ... have you searched for any explanation beforehand?

Comment: yes, that is how i got the colour eg. but i didnt get the grouping point.

Comment: If you got that example from the link I posted, the next sentence says: *"You can make several tokens optional by grouping them together using round brackets, and placing the question mark after the closing bracket."*. What more did you want to know?

Comment: @heldt, that AddedBytes cheat sheet isn't really a good reference.  It mashes together features from several regex flavors (some of which conflict with each other), and it contains several errors as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a quantifier which means "zero or one". It applies to the atom preceding it, therefore, here, the `u`.

It is one of the numerous regex metacharacters, which means, if you want to match a literal question mark, you'll have to escape it (as in `\?`), *except* in a character class.

As to your second example:

```
(first group)(second group)?(third group)
```

it has exactly the same meaning. The grouping operator, `(...)`, apart from allowing backreferences, also has the nice effect to turn anything into parens into an atom.

Which means, here, the text matched by the regex `second group` can appear 0 or 1 time, similarly to the `u` in `Colou?r`.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

`?` sign stands for "may be previous character"

`colou?r` means that `u` character may present or not. That is why 'color' and 'colour' both match this regex.

Comment: It stands for optionality in general, not specifically for characters.

Comment: @lkuty it depends on what you mean under "character":)

Comment: I don't think so. `regex?` is far more general than `character?`. In his _specific_ context it was a character.